# Programmatically create Firefox profiles

Tags: firefox-addon

**Question**:

Is there a simple programmatic way to create new Firefox profiles?

`nsIToolkitProfileService` looks like it might do the trick but the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIToolkitProfileService) say:

> Starting in Gecko 18 (Firefox 18.0 / Thunderbird 18.0 / SeaMonkey
>   2.15 / Firefox OS 1.0.1), you should no longer use either this service or nsIToolkitProfile

**Why**:

I am interested to do this because I think it could be used to get independent executables of Firefox running pretty easily (e.g., so one can have a wholly separate icon in the task bar for each app) without the need for the now defunct Prism/Chromeless/WebRunner projects.

My approach would be to create a Firefox add-on which allowed the user to specify a web app URL and then would auto-create for them a namespaced profile like "Executable1", "Executable2", etc. for the app as well as a batch file which would invoke the command line "-no-remote" argument against that profile and app (since -no-remote seems to require a profile to create a new instance (the "-new-instance" argument I have seen mentioned in a bug does not seem to work for me).

Comment: Do you still need help with this I found out some new info.

Comment: Yes, I would be interested if you wouldn't mind. It's not at the very top of my to-do list, but I would be interested in info on it if you have time, thanks!

Comment: Is that question too old? Actually you can create a profile just launching `firefox -CreateProfile myprofile` and would create it under random.myprofile name. Full firefox commands documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Mozilla/Opciones_de_linea_de_Comandos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that people either wanted to avoid main-thread I/O. Or there were talks to remove the profile manager from the app to make startup faster and simplify startup code in general, so that might be the reason. Seems like wiki user "victorporof" did make this edit, so you probably should ping him for an explanation (IIRC, he's got an @mozilla.com address you could easily google ;)

Anyway, a new profile isn't much more than an empty directory. The application will actually copy/create missing files as soon as it starts. So your add-on could just:

- Create an empty directory in the desired location.
- Open an instance: `-no-remote -profile $dir`
- Add icons or whatever.
- Be done with it.
- Optionally mess with profiles.ini, so that the new profile gets listed in the regular profile manager.

I regularly do stuff like this from command line, e.g.

```
mkdir -p central.profile && path/to/firefox -no-remote -profile $PWD/central.profile
```

Or just continue using `nsITOolkitProfileService` until it is actually removed. (That's what I would probably do). FWIW, there is even newish code still using it, like the (remote) debugger.

Also, might worth having a look at [the standalone profile manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Profile_Manager) they coded up.

Comment: Hi @nmaier can you please help me get more info on this. I'm trying to rename a profile using OS.File but simply renaming the fodler doesn't do this. Basically Im trying to find the info on which fiels the nsIToolkitProfileService is opening/closing/checking for locked/editing, can you please help me find this on MXR.

Comment: im trying to get in touch with victor guy i couldnt get his email so i tweeted him. are you sure though that victor was the one who made that change on the article?

Comment: See answer below, the message on the mdn article is false.

Answer (score 1):

So according to Neil from ask.m.o he said that the message saying not to use this service was auto put there when they made OS.File. It added that message falsely to this page. The service is available but OS.File is the prefered way. So I created some functions to do it with OS.File

LINK TO TOPIC: [ask.m.o: OS.File instead of nsiToolkitProfileService?](https://ask.mozilla.org/question/270/osfile-instead-of-nsitoolkitprofileservice/)

Here it is:
https://gist.github.com/yajd/9791029

It's still a work in progress needs much more fine tuning which I did in my addon Profilist, I'll release that soon and then post it here.

Comment: Hey man I released profilist to amo. The functions are within it, I didn't know `promise`s too well when I did it. So I have some touching up to do. But if you made progress on this project and I didnt get around to cleaning up the functions let me know, and that will kick start me to fine tune the functions. Try lifting the functions from there and using though, plz share any imrpvoments.

Comment: While I'd love to jump on the momentum, a number of other items have been bumped to the top of my priority list, though it is still very much my intention to get back to the work mentioned in the OP as possible, and I've added a todo/link back to this post for reference as I can find time to get back to this.