# Create New Firefox Profile in Java with Spaces?

Tags: java, firefox, command-line

I can easily create a new Firefox Profile in a custom directory using the command:

```
    String profileName = "ABC XYZ";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

    String dir = "C:\\My Custom Dir\\profileName";


    String executeCommand = "cmd.exe /c start firefox -CreateProfile \""  +  profileName.replaceAll("\s", "_")  + " " + customFirefoxProfileDir + "\"";

    Process process = rt.exec(executeCommand);
```

The problem I'm encountering is that if I don't replace empty spaces in the `profileName` with an underscore (or some other character) the Profile will be generated only using the first word in `profileName` (i.e, ABC instead of ABC XYZ).

After researching this for some time, I believe this queer phenomenon stems from the fact that [Firefox does not allow spaces in the Profile Name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#user_profile).

> -CreateProfile profile_name
>
> Create a new profile in the default directory, but do not start the
> application. The profile will be named profile_name in the profile
> manager, the profile_name must not contain spaces().

While I can always automatically replace empty spaces with underscores, the problem is that there's no way for me to enforce this convention as some of the profiles are being created manually through the Choose User Profile Dialog with spaces.

Oddly, when clicking [Create Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biziy.png) in the Firefox - Choose User Profile dialog I am able to name it whatever I want - including **with spaces**.

So my question is: Is there a way to create a new Firefox Profile programmatically (in Java) while including spaces in the actual Profile Name?

I tried surrounding the `profileName` with double quotes but it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure if typo on question or in actual code but `.replaceAll("\s", "_")` should probably be `.replaceAll("\\s", "_")`

Comment: .replaceAll("\s", "_") works just fine

Comment: Not sure what you mean since `"\s"` will not compile in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B.t.w. here is the 21 year (!) old bug entry that explains why this is not possible: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51509

but maybe you can learn more from the accepted answer to this question?

[Programmatically create Firefox profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711327/programmatically-create-firefox-profiles)

In any case I would recommend using the alternative method for runtime.exec that takes an array to avoid messing with extra quotes:

```
rt.exec(new String[] {"mkdir", "C:\\my test"});
```

And in doubt watch with sysinternals procmon what is really happening behind the screens.

Also consider dynamically composing a `.bat` or `.cmd` or similar script file that you can execute from Java and is easier to write and debug. Example for a createprofile.cmd file:

```
@echo off
REM Put REM before the first line if you want to debug this script

IF "%~1"=="" ( echo please pass two arguments: the profile name and directory && goto END )
IF "%~2"=="" ( echo please pass two arguments, the profile name and directory && goto END )

REM Use %~1 instead of %1 to get rid of the double quotes of the invocation
set "FF_PROFILE_NAME=%~1"
set "FF_PROFILE_DIR=%~2"

IF exist "%FF_PROFILE_DIR%" ( echo directory already exists ) ELSE ( mkdir "%FF_PROFILE_DIR%" || exit %ERRORLEVEL%)

REM See: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profiles.ini_file
set "PROFILE_CONFIG=%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini"

REM Let's make a backup first
copy "%PROFILE_CONFIG%" "%PROFILE_CONFIG%.bak-%RANDOM%%RANDOM%" >NUL

REM Find the highest profile number
REM TODO: Performance, stop looking if we found the highest profilenumber
REM TODO: Stop with error if we reach the highest profile number that we check for
FOR /L %%G IN (0,1,99) DO (findstr "\[Profile%%G\]" "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini" >NUL && set "LAST_PROFILE=%%G")

SET /a NEXT_PROFILE=%LAST_PROFILE%+1

REM Write the new configuration section the ini file, appending it to the end:
ECHO.>> %PROFILE_CONFIG%
ECHO [Profile%NEXT_PROFILE%]>> %PROFILE_CONFIG%
ECHO Name=%FF_PROFILE_NAME%>> %PROFILE_CONFIG%
REM Escape with caret ^ the meaning of file descriptor numbers
ECHO IsRelative=^0>> %PROFILE_CONFIG%
ECHO Path=%FF_PROFILE_DIR%>> %PROFILE_CONFIG%
ECHO.>> %PROFILE_CONFIG%

:END
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and wow never thought this might be related to a 21 year old bug! Seems like some things never get fixed! In either case, would you kindly be able to add example of a .bat or .cmd script that can be called from Java that would achieve the intended purpose? I'm not familiar with .bat/,cmd only Java..Also I'm assuming your recommendation of using alternative method for runtime.exec wasn't intended to answer the question rather a side suggestion. Is that correct?

Comment: It wasn't a side suggestion but an alternative solution, why bother setting up profiles if you can just point to an empty directory and start with that? But if you really want the profile to appear in the profile manager etc. you could edit %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini yourself and put in as much spaces as you like, see the docs at: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profiles.ini_file and this hint https://superuser.com/questions/138275/move-firefox-user-settings-to-another-folder-on-same-machine#comment2000671_138275

Comment: If you can update your answer with .bat/.cmd file to achieve intended purpose I would award bounty to you! Thanks!

Comment: Added a sample script, to illustrate what is possible, please do your own testing

Comment: Thanks, upvoted and accepted. I did not test yet hopefully it works!

Answer (score 0):

you could try using different whitsepace character than the "keyboard spacebar".

you might want to take a look at the top 2 Answers in this thread:
[All the Whitespace Characters? Is it language independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169006/all-the-whitespace-characters-is-it-language-independent)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I am specifically looking for a solution that allows me to create a profile using the "keyboard spacebar" not a "hack" that mimics the spacebar.